# Python not returning output

Tags: python

```
def get_prime_factors(N):
    factors = list()
    divisor = 2
    while (divisor <= N):
        if (N % divisor) == 0:
            factors.append(divisor)
            N = N//divisor
        else:
            divisor += 1
    return factors
```

I'm trying to run this small project however I'm not getting any output either from my python IDLE shell, terminal or VSCode. any errors in my code?

I made a test script and it outputted normal, not sure why this one has no output.

running Python 3.10.6
on MacBook Pro M1

thanks!

Comment: Is that all of the code?  You haven't included a call to that function and there are no print statements.

Comment: How are you calling the function? Are you?

Comment: The code shown does not feature anything that would create output.

Comment: This function returns a value, which means the calling function of this function will receive the output value of this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've defined the function, you must call it then print the result. Like this:

```
def get_prime_factors(N):
    factors = list()
    divisor = 2
    while (divisor <= N):
        if (N % divisor) == 0:
            factors.append(divisor)
            N = N//divisor
        else:
            divisor += 1
    return factors

# get an input
n = input("Enter a number: ")

# call the function and assign return to a variabe
prime_factors = get_prime_factors(int(n))

# print the result
print(prime_factors)
```

You probably also want to prompt the user for input, so I've included code to do that in my answer.

PS: I have another [answer about why you have to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72385858/function-at-the-end-of-code-why-do-i-have-to-place-it/72385887#72385887). That answer might be helpful if you're a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call the function to see an output.

```
print(get_prime_factors(3))
```